# SQL Server not accepting DECLARE in INTO Statement

Tags: sql-server-2008, while-loop, insert-into

I'm somewhat new to SQL Server and am trying to use a while loop inside of an `INTO` statement, but for some reason SQL Server is not letting me `DECLARE` my variable inside of the `INTO` statement... seems to be okay w/ the while loop though, but I need to be able to `DECLARE` and define my variable to use in the while loop...any ideas?

```
--Calculations portion of query
SELECT 
    FNL.* 
INTO 
    #Final_Calc 
FROM 
    (
     DECLARE @i INT
     SET @i = 0

     WHILE (@StartDte + @i <= @EndDte)
     BEGIN
          SET @i = @i + 1       

          SELECT 
             YEAR(ACD.WorkDte) AS WorkDte, 
             'LOB - ALL ACM' AS RptType, 
             'Month' AS RptLvl
          FROM 
             #FinalResults ACD 
          WHERE 
             ACD.WorkDte BETWEEN @StartDte AND @StartDte + @i 
          GROUP BY 
             Year(ACD.WorkDte), ACD.LOB
     END
     GO) fnl
```

So, it is not liking `DECLARE @i INT` portion...

Comment: Why dont you just declare `@i` before the select statement

Comment: There is a few errors in your code .. 1. `Declared @i INT` and `SET @i=0` in a sub query.  2. `WHILE` loop cannot be in a sub query.   3. `@startDte + @i` needs to use `DATEADD` assuming @startDte is a date or datetime datatype.   4. `GO` is before sub query alias `) fnl`.   Need to clarify with some sample data and output of result

Comment: If I do that then the SET @i = 0 goes red and SQL dsnt except it...then if I move the DECLARE @i and SET @i = 0 bfr the select statment the WHILE goes red and SQL then dsnt like my While loop...dsnt seem like I can win here lol...

Comment: My guess is you are coming from a programming background and are assuming something that just ain't true in the SQL world. Loops, for example, should be used in very few circumstances. Post an example of your data structure and what your expected output is.